# rolling join in data.table to multiple (GPS) points

Tags: r, join, merge, gps, data.table

Last week I asked this question: [How to efficiently calculate distance between GPS points in one dataset and GPS points in another data set using data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212103/how-to-efficiently-calculate-distance-between-gps-points-in-one-dataset-and-gps)  on the matching of GPS coordinates of a gps tracker with the Gps coordinates of bus stop. User Hugh, gave an answer that works many times faster than the solution I eventually came up with. However, there is one problem I cannot get fixed in his/her code (I feel like I really tried all iterations possibilities of the code) I need to get a rolling join in which multiple bus stops that are near a GPS point get listed. In the current code only the nearest is given, but a GPS coordinate can of course be near multiple bus stops. I know this means I will have to turn around the Y and the X in the rolling join somewhere , but somehow it just doesnt work. Can someone maybe point me towards a solution?

All the code and full explanation can be found in the original question, but this is how I create the data:

```
# create GPS data
number_of_GPS_coordinates <- 1000000
set.seed(1)
gpsdata<-data.frame(id=1:number_of_GPS_coordinates, 
                    device_id = 1,
                    latitude=runif(number_of_GPS_coordinates,50.5,53.5), 
                    longitude=runif(number_of_GPS_coordinates,4,7))
# create Bus stop data

set.seed(1)
number_of_bus_stops <-  55000
busdata<-data.frame(id=1:number_of_bus_stops, 
                    name=replicate(number_of_bus_stops, paste(sample(LETTERS, 15, replace=TRUE), collapse="")),
                    latitude=runif(number_of_bus_stops,50.5,53.5), 
                    longitude=runif(number_of_bus_stops,4,7))
```

And this is the function that does work for me, but is still not very fast (much faster than my first attempt):

```
check_if_close <- function(dataset1     = GPS.Utrecht.to.Gouda,       
                           dataset2     = bus_stops,     
                           n.splits     = 500,
                           desired.dist = .2){

# dataset1 needs at least the columns 
#  - "id", 
#  - "device_id"
#  - "latitude"
#  - "longitude"

# dataset2 needs at least the columns 
#  - "id", 
#  - "name"
#  - "latitude"
#  - "longitude"

# these are the average coordinates of the Netherlands. A change of ,.0017 in latitude leads to a change of 189 meters 
# spDistsN1(matrix(c(5.2913, 52.1326), ncol=2), matrix(c(5.2913, 52.1326+.0017), ncol=2), longlat=TRUE)*1000
# [1] 189.1604
# this means that the latitude slices we can cut (the subsection of) the Netherlands is have to be at least .0017 wide.
# if we look at the Netherlands a whole this would mean we can use max  (53.5-50.5)/.0017 = 1765 slices.
# if we look only at a small subsection (because we are only looking a a single trip for example we need much less slices.  

# 1) we only select the variables we need from dataset 1
  dataset1 <- setDT(dataset1)[,c("id", "device_id", "latitude", "longitude")]
  setnames(dataset1, old = c("id", "latitude", "longitude"), new = c("id_dataset1", "latitude_gps", "longitude_gps"))

# 2) we only select the variables we need from dataset 2
  dataset2 <- setDT(dataset2)[,c("id", "name", "latitude", "longitude")]
  setnames(dataset2, old = c("id", "latitude", "longitude"), new = c("id_dataset2", "latitude_feature", "longitude_feature"))

# 3) only keep subet of dataset2 that falls within dataset 1. 
#    There is no reason to check if features are close that already fall out of the GPS coordinates in the trip we want to check
#    We do add a 0.01 point margin around it to be on the save side. Maybe a feature falls just out the GPS coordinates, 
#    but is still near to a GPS point
  dataset2 <- dataset2[latitude_feature  %between%  (range(dataset1$latitude_gps) + c(-0.01, +0.01)) 
                       & longitude_feature %between% (range(dataset1$longitude_gps) + c(-0.01, +0.01)), ]

# 4) we cut the dataset2 into slices on the latitude dimension
#    some trial  and error is involved getting the right amount. if you add to many you get a large and redudant amount of empty values
#    if you add to few you get you need to check too many GPS to feauture distances per slice



dataset2[, range2 := as.numeric(Hmisc::cut2(dataset2$latitude_feature, g=n.splits))]

# 5) calculate the ranges of the slices we just created
ranges <- dataset2[,list(Min=min(latitude_feature), Max= max(latitude_feature)), by=range2][order(range2)]
setnames(ranges, old = c("range2", "Min", "Max"), new = c("latitude_range", "start", "end"))


# 6) now we assign too which slice every GPS coordinate in our dataset1 belongs
#    this is super fast when using data.table grammar
elements1 <- dataset1$latitude_gps
ranges <- setDT(ranges)[data.table(elements1), on = .(start <= elements1, end >=elements1)]
ranges[, rowID := seq_len(.N)]
dataset1[,rowID := seq_len(.N)]
setkey(dataset1, rowID)
setkey(ranges, rowID)
dataset1<-dataset1[ranges]

# 7) this is the actual function we use to check if a datapoint is nearby.
#    potentially there are faster function to do this??
checkdatapoint <- function(p, h, dist=desired.dist) {
  distances <- spDistsN1(data.matrix(filter(dataset1,latitude_range==h)[,c("longitude_gps","latitude_gps")]), 
                         p,
                         longlat=TRUE) # in km
  return(which(distances <= dist)) # distance is now set to 200 meters
}

# 8) we assign a ID to the dataset1 starting again at every slice.
#    we need this to later match the data again 
dataset1[, ID2 := sequence(.N), by = latitude_range]

# 9) here we loop over all the splits and for every point check if there is a feature nearby in the slice it falls in
#    to be on the save side we also check the slice left and right of it, just to make sure we do not miss features that
#    are nearby, but just fall in a different slice.
#         9a: create an empty list we fill with dataframes later 
TT<-vector("list", length=n.splits)
#         9b: loop over the number of slices using above defined function

for(i in 1:n.splits){
  datapoints.near.feature<-apply(data.matrix(dataset2[range2 %in% c(i-1,i, i+1), c("longitude_feature","latitude_feature")]), 1, checkdatapoint, h=i)
#         9c: if in that slice there was no match between a GPS coordinate and an nearby feature, we create an empty list input
    if(class(datapoints.near.feature)=="integer"|class(datapoints.near.feature)=="matrix"){
    TT[[i]] <-NULL
  } else {
#         9d: if there was a match we get a list of data point that are named
    names(datapoints.near.feature)    <- dataset2[range2 %in% c(i-1,i, i+1), name]
#         9e: then we 'melt' this list into  data.frame
    temp <- melt(datapoints.near.feature)
#         9f: then we transform it into a data.table and change the names
    setDT(temp)
    setnames(temp, old=c("value", "L1"), new= c("value", "feature_name"))
#         9h: then we only select the data point in dataset1 that fall in the current slice give them an 
#             ID and merge them with the file of nearby busstops
    gpsdata.f <- dataset1[latitude_range==i, ]
    gpsdata.f[, rowID2 := seq_len(.N)]
    setkey(gpsdata.f, key = "rowID2")
    setkey(temp, key = "value")
    GPS.joined.temp <- merge(x = gpsdata.f, y = temp, by.x= "rowID2", by.y= "value", all.x=TRUE)
#         9i: we only keep the unique entries and for every slice save them to the list
    GPS.joined.unique.temp <- unique(GPS.joined.temp, by=c("id_dataset1", "feature_name"))
    TT[[i]] <-  GPS.joined.unique.temp 
    cat(paste0(round(i/n.splits*100), '% completed'), " \r"); flush.console()


    #cat(i/n.splits*100, " \r"); flush.console()

  }

}

# 10) now we left join the original dataset and and the data point that are near a feature
finallist<- merge(x = dataset1, 
                  y = rbindlist(TT[vapply(TT, Negate(is.null), NA)]), 
                  by.x= "id_dataset1", 
                  by.y= "id_dataset1", 
                  all.x=TRUE)

# 11) we add a new logical variable to check if any bus stop is near
finallist[, nearby := TRUE][is.na(feature_name), nearby := FALSE] # add a dummy to check if any bus stop is nearby.

# 12) if a point is near multiple features at once these are listed in a vector,
#     instead of having duplicate rows with teh same id but different features
finallist <- unique(setDT(finallist)[order(id_dataset1, feature_name), list(feature_name=list(feature_name), id=id_dataset1, lat=latitude_gps.x, lon=longitude_gps.x, nearby=nearby), by=id_dataset1], by="id_dataset1")

return(finallist)
}
```

This is the code @Hugh proposed, which is super fast and almost does the same thing. except that multiple bus stations to a point are not listed and only the nearest ones.

```
# create GPS data
number_of_GPS_coordinates <- 20000
set.seed(1)
gpsdata<-as.data.frame(cbind(id=1:number_of_GPS_coordinates, 
                             lat=runif(number_of_GPS_coordinates,50.5,53.5), 
                             lon=runif(number_of_GPS_coordinates,4,7)))

# create some busstop data. In this case only 2000 bus stops
set.seed(1)
number_of_bus_stops <- 2000
stop<-as.data.frame(gpsdata[sample(nrow(gpsdata), number_of_bus_stops), -1]) # of course do not keep id variable
stop$lat<-stop$lat+rnorm(number_of_bus_stops,0,.0005)
stop$lon<-stop$lon+rnorm(number_of_bus_stops,0,.0005)
busdata.data<-cbind(stop, name=replicate(number_of_bus_stops, paste(sample(LETTERS, 15, replace=TRUE), collapse="")))

names(busdata.data) <- c("latitude_bustops",  "longitude_bustops", "name")
library(data.table)
library(hutils)
setDT(gpsdata)
setDT(busdata.data)

gps_orig <- copy(gpsdata)
busdata.orig <- copy(busdata.data)

setkey(gpsdata, lat)

# Just to take note of the originals
gpsdata[, gps_lat := lat + 0]
gpsdata[, gps_lon := lon + 0]

busdata.data[, lat := latitude_bustops + 0]
busdata.data[, lon := longitude_bustops + 0]


setkey(busdata.data, lat)

gpsID_by_lat <- 
  gpsdata[, .(id), keyby = "lat"]


By_latitude <- 
  busdata.data[gpsdata, 
               on = "lat",

               # within 0.5 degrees of latitude
               roll = 0.5, 
               # +/-
               rollends = c(TRUE, TRUE),

               # and remove those beyond 0.5 degrees
               nomatch=0L] %>%
  .[, .(id_lat = id,
        name_lat = name,
        bus_lat = latitude_bustops,
        bus_lon = longitude_bustops,
        gps_lat,
        gps_lon),
    keyby = .(lon = gps_lon)]

setkey(busdata.data, lon)

By_latlon <-
  busdata.data[By_latitude,
               on = c("name==name_lat", "lon"),

               # within 0.5 degrees of latitude
               roll = 0.5, 
               # +/-
               rollends = c(TRUE, TRUE),
               # and remove those beyond 0.5 degrees
               nomatch=0L]

By_latlon[, distance := haversine_distance(lat1 = gps_lat, 
                                           lon1 = gps_lon,
                                           lat2 = bus_lat,
                                           lon2 = bus_lon)]

By_latlon[distance < 0.2]
```

Can someone help me adjust the code in such a way that not only the nearest bus stop, but all stops within 200 meters are given (in a list, or separate rows)